# Create an array out of several arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing namespace information:

```
$array = [
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Middleware'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Phone'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Mail'],
    ['App', 'Mail', 'Sender'],
    ['App', 'Box'],
];
```

Now I want to build a single array or object that should show the namespace information in an hirachic way:

```
$result = [
    ['App' => 
        ['Classes' => 
            [
                'Auth',
                'Middleware',
                'Phone',
            ]
        ],
        ['Mail' => 
            ['Sender']
        ],
        ['Box'] => []
    ]
]
```

I have tried some recursive functions, but all I get is a flat array...

---

```
private function createNamespaceHirachy( $namespaces ) {


        foreach ($namespaces as $index => $namespace) {
            $namespaces[$namespace] = [];
            $namespaces[$namespace] = $this->createNamespaceHirachy($namespaces[$namespace]);
        }


    return $namespaces;
}
```

Sorry, it may be much more simple, but I'm brainstuck :-/

Comment: Show us that recursive function which you tried.

Comment: Please _show us_ what you tried (and with what exact results), and explain your reasoning.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135624/multi-dimensional-array-hierarchy-from-key-name/56135929#56135929

Comment: You need not use recursion at all.

Comment: So this can never go four levels deep?

Comment: A simple `foreach` should be all you need to do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Middleware'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Phone'],
    ['App', 'Classes', 'Auth'],
    ['App', 'Mail'],
    ['App', 'Mail', 'Sender'],
    ['App', 'Box'],
];

$hierarchy = [];

foreach($array as $each_data){
    $curr_hierarchy = &$hierarchy;
    foreach($each_data as $each_namespace){
        if(!isset($curr_hierarchy[$each_namespace])){
            $curr_hierarchy[$each_namespace] = [];
        }

        $curr_hierarchy = &$curr_hierarchy[$each_namespace];
    }
}

print_r($hierarchy);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/AVVZI

- We loop over each hierarchical data in `$array` one by one.
- We initialize the final resulting array as `$hierarchy` in the above code.
- Now, inside the inner foreach loop, we maintain a current hierarchy stage. In other words, `$curr_hierarchy` contains the current level we are in.
- As we loop over inside the inner `foreach` loop, if the current stage does not have the namespace as it's key, we assign it and go one level further deep by passing it as the new current hierarchy.
- Note that the pass by reference `&` is necessary to reflect changes overall to the array, else, it creates a new clone keeping your final array empty.
- You may also notice the child elements itself being an array as well. I think that's fine for your current context, but do let me know if that wasn't what you desired.

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex Happy to help :)

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex  your expected output  is different from this answer output. Please confirm once.

Comment: @vivek_23  your output is not same what OP asked for.`Auth` needs to be a value inside `classes` array not an empty array with index `auth` and so on for others

Comment: @AlivetoDie I did mention that in my last statement but it seems fine from OP's end.

Comment: @vivek_23   I have just raised a question to you and OP both to clarify the confusion. If you can correct your answer, then you have to do that. Or we can wait for final verdict of OP (which i think will not come, as he already gone by marking the answer quickly)

Comment: I marked the question as solved as the answer of vivek_23 helped me a lot

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex but the answer isn't correct. It's not what you asked for.

Comment: @Andreas It's true that the child elements need to be literal strings and not empty arrays. But I don't see how that would cause a problem when the OP would be iterating over them for some of his purposes. It's better than doing an is_array() check all the time.

Comment: If the array is going to be json_encoded and sent out to users or clients then I think it would matter.

Comment: @Andreas That would be still be the choice of developers. Both ways would be correct.

Comment: agreed with @Andreas, but at the end of the day it's OP's call. leave it, and go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is snippet for your scenario

```
$results = json_decode(json_encode($array)); // converting to object to play
$tree    = null;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    // checking first getting address of it to play
    $thisref                          = &$refs->{$result[0]}; 
    $tree->{$result[0]}               = &$thisref;
    // checking for level 1 if not empty
    $thisref                          = &$refs->{$result[1]};
    $tree->{$result[0]}->{$result[1]} = &$thisref;
    // checking for level 2 if not empty
    if (!empty($result[2])) {
        $thisref                                        = &$refs->{$result[2]};
        $refs->{$result[0]}->{$result[1]}[] = $result[2];//&$thisref;
        $refs->{$result[0]}->{$result[1]} = array_unique($refs->{$result[0]}->{$result[1]});
    }

}
// finally converting back to array
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($tree), true));
```

[**Working demo**](https://3v4l.org/2udcX).